# android:button = @null in radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button

I made a RadioButton with images.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/radioType"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioAlc"
    style="@style/navbar_button"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/policeradio"
    android:text="Barrage" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioCrash"
    style="@style/navbar_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/carcrashradio"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:text="Accidente" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioMarch"
    style="@style/navbar_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/marchradio"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:text="Manifestation" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioRadar"
    style="@style/navbar_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/radarradio"
    android:text="Radar" />
</RadioGroup>
```

the problem is that with

```
<item name="android:button">@null</item>
```

I can remove the radio button, to let the user click the image, but it seems that it keeps the space to show it. In my case, I would like to remove that extra space that is bothering me !
Is it possible???

I apply that style

```
<style name="navbar_button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

[image: with radio]
[image: without radio]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you use other styles we can't see here, but if I copy your code in a layout file and add this to my styles.xml:

```
<style name="navbar_button">
   <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>
```

it works fine and there is no extra space.

EDIT:
You have to add the item `<item name="android:padding">0dp</item>` to your navbar_button style, then it works on Android 2.3, too.

Comment: Just tried it out - if I use <item name="android:button">@null</item>, the space will disappear... Have you tried to change @null to 0dp? Which Android SDK version do you use to compile and run it?

Comment: I can't change @null to 0dp -> Compilatio error.
SDK : API 10+

Comment: Ow, sorry for the 0dp answer ;) It's still working here with API 10+. Does it work for you if you give the attribute directly to a RadioButton with android:button="@null"?

Comment: If I put it directly, nothing change :(

Comment: The thing I'm using to a new project for that snippet, so there is nothing more that could change

Comment: Does already the preview in Eclipse show you the wrong layout?

Comment: Nop. Eclipse preview don't show any problem ! I'm testing with a samsung fame and htc nexus one, and both show the same pb

Comment: Try to add <item name="android:padding">0dp</item> to your style, this worked for me also on a 2.3 emulator.

Comment: It works ! I tried it before, but who knows !!! Tx a lot ! Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as resolved !

Comment: No problem - perhaps Eclipse needed a moment to realize that your style has changed, this can happen sometimes ;)